# Multicollinearity/Redundancy

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

In a regression problem would it be a problem if I included redundant variables? Ie. Total number of red birds, total number of blue birds, total number of red and blue birds. That would blow up my model correct?

Comment: It would cause your model to have a non-unique solution, and consequently cause trouble for all common model fitting algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to understand the problem with your example is: suppose I have one more blue bird than I had before, and I observe some change in my response.  Is this change attributable to the fact that I have one more blue bird, or one more (blue or red) bird?  There's really no way to make that call.

The algebra goes like this.  For linear regression, any solution vector $\beta$ satisfies:

$$ X^{t}X \beta = X^{t} y $$

If you introduce redundancies in design, then $X^{t} X$ becomes a singular matrix.  This means that there is some non-zero vector $v$ for which:

$$ X^{t} X v = 0 $$

Then $\beta + \lambda v$ is also a solution to your regression problem for any number $\lambda$, because:

$$ X^{t}X (\beta + \lambda v) = X^{t} X \beta + \lambda X^{t} X v = X^{t} X \beta $$

So you've introduced non-uniqueness in your solutions.  The algorithms used to solve linear regression problems are often predicated on the assumption that there is a unique solution, so redundancies in design tend to break them.  The details of why this happens take some study of computational mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Matthew Drury has suggested, you should avoid obvious correlations amongst input variables.

If you are not sure, if your model contains collinear inputs, try checking for multi-collinearity using metrics like VIF or Kappa factor. One option to solve it is to remove redundant variables, the other is to transform (like taking logarithm) one of the variables. But this will not eliminate multi-collinearity all-together. It will only make sure that your model would not 'blow up' altogether.

Comment: I'll add s shrinkage operator like ridge regression to your list of blow up protections.